# Add another subtitle to dynamic view cell

Tags: ios, dynamic, view, prototype, cell

Quick Question.  I am trying to add another cell in the Prototype cell.  I have add the line "cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;" but don't get anything on the cell.  Can someone help.

Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...


    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", person.surname, person.firstname];
    cell.textLabel.text = fullname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.inEvent.name;
    cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "add another cell in the Prototype cell." ? I think what you want, based in your code, is add another `UILabel` to your code. From the default `UITableViewCell`, you only have two, the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`. If you want one more, you have to create yourself.

Notice that you are setting the same label twice.

```
cell.textLabel.text = fullname; //setting first time
cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.inEvent.name;
cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;  //setting second time. This will set a new text to 'textLabel', losing its previous content (fullname)
```

You can allocate a new one and add as subview of the cell's contentView inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. But I really suggest to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, using the Interface Builder to position your labels as you want, creating `IBOutlets` for them, and setting it's text in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.